# Divide in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, divide

In SQL Server 2005 Express, the result is below

> SELECT 100 / 15 --Result 6

But I wanna get approximate value 7 (like using calculator)

> 100 / 15 = 6.6666..

How to make it in SQL Server?

Comment: Now I got it. Thanks all :). SELECT ROUND(100 / 15.00,0)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to use decimal numbers e.g. 100 / 15.0. If you use integers the result is interpreted as an integer and truncated to the largest integer that is smaller than or equal to the result.

Answer (score 8):

SELECT cast(100 as float) / (15 as float)

Answer (score 5):

You want SQL Server to perform floating-point divison, as opposed to integer division. If you're using literal values, as in your example, suffix the denominator with `.0` to force SQL Server to treat it as a floating-point value.

```
SELECT 100 / 15.0
```

Otherwise, make sure you declare your variables as `FLOAT`.

Answer (score 2):

Try declaring variables as floats:

```
DECLARE @var1 FLOAT
DECLARE @var2 FLOAT
SET @var1 = 100
SET @var2 = 15
SELECT @var1 / @var2
```